# How to hardcode bindings in cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

Good day. Does anyone know a way to hardcode
`org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceProperties # setBindings`

I need this so that when using the microservice, it is not possible to make changes through the application.yml - to reduce the space for potential errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream...", ""). You can use java `-D` and provide properties from command line. You can also had code then in your main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoStreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =  SpringApplication.run(DemoStreamApplication.class,
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.echo-in-0.destination=echo",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.echo-in-0.group=echogroup");
. . .
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm very glad to see the answer from the author